# PostgreSQL Query to Excel Sheet

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql, debian, data-extraction

I need to export some data from PostgreSQL to Excel (quick  customer wish), and the last time Excel had serious problems opening or importing my COPYd csv files (line endings, utf-8 encoding, etc), and it took me an hour at best.

Does someone know a quick, elegant solution that generates a real Excel file? Like a small shell script or the like?

I want this to be done either on my Linux box (Debian 5.0 Lenny) or on Windows (XP or higher).

Comment: It was ME taking a hour getting Excel to open and import my CSV file, because at first the encoding was wrong, then multiline strings broke the import, etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could install the [PostgreSQL ODBC driver](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) on the Windows machine, and then connect Excel to the database [like explained in this blog post](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/how-to-query-oracle-from-excel-2007/) (except using ODBC rather than OLEDB).

I haven't tested this. I'm not really sure if this makes it any easier than exporting CSV and fixing it (given what Excel is like).

EDIT (thanks @Tometzky): **The best solution** is to use the PostgreSQL ODBC driver to connect Microsoft Access to the database and from Access export to Excel.

Comment: +1 Good idea. I have the datasource installed already anyway, so this really should be the fastest way.

Comment: +1 But I'd recommend using Access for importing data from Postres and then export from Access to Excel.

Comment: +1 @Tometzky: This comment would be my accepted answer, because only access allowed me to select the tables from my ODBC driver. Excel could not find any table. I upvoted another answer of you in another question instead :)

Comment: @Tometzky: Good idea, I'll edit that into the answer (sorry that I get rep that sort of belongs to you)

Comment: I configured a Postgresql connection with oledb odbc bridge and  the postgresql odbc driver and it works (MS Office 2007). At the end of configuration is also the chance to select the desired table or view.

Comment: If you are looking for a 64 bit solution, try  http://code.google.com/p/visionmap/downloads/detail?name=setup_psqlODBC_x64_8.3.4.0.exe&can=2&q=

Comment: This killed me for a while, so to future readers:  You will first need to set up the ODBC connection. To set up the ODBC: Click on the Start Menu.
Select Control Panel.
Select Administrative Tools and double click the Data Sources (ODBC) icon.
Click on the System DSN tab. More detailed article that I pulled the ODBC set-up text from: http://www.stoneedge.com/help/mergedProjects/3rdparty/Creating_ODBC_Connections_in_Microsoft_Windows.htm

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can use Power Query Add-in and the .Net PostgreSQL Data Provider for importing PostgreSQL data into Excel 2010 or Excel 2013...

Download
http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39379

How to for using PostgreSQL:
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Connect-to-a-PostgreSQL-database-bf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4

Comment: Hi just fyi apparently this does not work for all versions of office (eg Student 2013) for a stupid drop menu bug - this post describes the issue - I think only works for Pro (worked for me on office 2010 pro):
http://superuser.com/questions/950100/connect-to-postgresql-database-from-excel-2013-power-query-with-npgsql